# how to setup p2pool for dogecoin?

Tags: p2pool, dogecoin

I try use --net 'dogecoin',but display errors:invalid choice: 'dogecoin',How should I do to make p2pool join dogecoin Network

Comment: When you supply `--net dogecoin` program does look for `p2pool/networks/dogecoin.py` which seems that doesn't exist at all. Also, seems the Dogecoin mining where merged to the Litecoin one, so the dogecoin-p2pool is not likely to use. As I understand, just point it to `--net litecoin` and your doge miner would work. NOTE: I say what I understand reading the guides.

Answer (score 1):

This repo https://github.com/Rav3nPL/p2pool-rav

contains an updated version of p2pool that i know working with dogecoin network

Comment: If you inspect https://github.com/Rav3nPL/p2pool-rav/tree/master/p2pool/networks would see that in fact dogecoin still is not in the `p2pool/networks` directory. Seems the that the original p2pool is able to mine with dogecoin too.

Answer (score 0):

Dogecoin was removed from p2pool because auxpow was added to it. You have to use the `--net litecoin` arg with mergemining setup to mine Dogecoin on p2pool.